# How to use Linq Extensions Methods using dynamic types?

Tags: linq, extension-methods, ienumerable, helper

My problem is: I don't know my types at compile time, because some of them are emitted at runtime. Anyone knows a library that implements non-generic IEnumerable Linq Helper Extension Methods?

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable Join(
    this IEnumerable source, 
    Type outerType, 
    Type innerType, 
    IEnumerable inner, 
    LambdaExpression outerKeySelector, 
    LambdaExpression innerKeySelector, 
    LambdaExpression resultSelector)
{    
    var method = 
        typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
            .Single(x => x.Name == "Join" && x.GetParameters().Length == 5);

    return 
        method.MakeGenericMethod(
            outerType, 
            innerType, 
            innerKeySelector.ReturnType, 
            resultSelector.ReturnType)
            .Invoke(
                null, 
                new object[] { source, inner, outerKeySelector.Compile(),
                innerKeySelector.Compile(), 
                resultSelector.Compile() }) as IEnumerable;
    }
```

**EDIT**:

This is how I construct my lambda expressions:

```
var property = myType.GetProperty("SomeProperty");
var p = Expression.Parameter(myType, "p");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, property), p);
```

So, my lambda would be

```
p => p.SomeProperty
```

Comment: How are you building lambda expressions if you don't know the types?

Comment: Types are emitted (Dynamic Assemblies), so I know them in runtime, but not in compile time.

Comment: So the lambda expressions are emitted as well?

Comment: Yes, they are constructed in runtime. I updated the question to include this information.

Comment: So at what point do you actually _use_ the types that are emitted?  Or is everything completely dynamic?

Comment: Everything is completely dynamic. I use Reflection to use everything.